# Negative Binomial Fit with glm.nb in R - Error

Tags: r, regression, data-fitting

I have to test my data in three distributions: Poisson, Negative Binomial and Geometric.

To test Poisson, I'm using:

```
glm(formula = frequencia ~ frequencia , 
               family = poisson(link = "log"), 
               data = data_fit,
              method = "glm.fit")
```

And the results are ok.

To test geometric, I'm using:

```
glm(formula = frequencia ~ frequencia, 
            family= negative.binomial(theta = 1),
            data=data_fit)
```

And the results are ok too.

But, to test negative binomial, I'm using:

```
MASS::glm.nb(formula = frequencia ~ frequencia, 
                       data = data_fit,
                       link = "log",
                       method="glm.fit")
```

And i'm receiving this error:

**Error in while ((it <- it + 1) < limit && abs(del) > eps) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

My data_fit is a vector/dataframe with 1000 values; all values in vector are the same and equal to 0.06.

[image]

I'm looking for the AIC, BIC and Deviance results of glm.nb function and parameters of negative binomial distribution.

Is there any way to find the values (AIC, BIC, Deviance, Parameters) with a zero variance, like the problem that i have?

Comment: It's hard to answer a question about distributions of data that no one else has access to. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with.

Comment: @camille, i know it's hard, but is what i said, my data is a vector with 1000 values equal to 0.06.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize that repeated value was the entirety of your dataset. I don't totally get the purpose of this, but when I ran your last block of code and then ran `warnings()`, I got this: "In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 0.600000". It's been a while since my last probability class, but is negative binomial a discrete distribution?

Comment: @camille, i solve those warnings multiplying this values for 100, to remove decimal cases for test. I'm translating SAS code to R, and sometimes those cases happen and we have a vector with just one value. Both negtive binomial, geometric and poisson are discrete distribution. They count the number of events that happen.

Comment: @camille, do you know other ways to do those types of distribution fits with R or Python?